# Multiplying two columns based on header name

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get to multiply two columns based on the header name (can change position every time - so a fixed cell range does not work).

So far, I got the following piece

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lrow As Long
Dim Amount, Bill, USD As Range
Dim Rngheaders As Range

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CSV Data PR")
Set Rngheaders = ws.Range("1:1")
lrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row - 1

Set Amount = ws.Rows(1).Find(What:="Amount")
Set Bill = ws.Rows(1).Find(What:="Bill.qty")
Set USD = ws.Rows(1).Find(What:="In USD")

ws.Range(USD.Address).Offset(1, 0).Resize(lrow) = Range(Amount.Address).Offset(1, 0) * Range(Bill.Address).Offset(1, 0)
```

This works, except for the fact that it only ever calculates row 2 (I need it to calculate row by row).

**Desired** output should look something like:

[image: Output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to add a loop to cycle through each row.  You did part of the work by finding the last row.  You also set the first row to `Rngheaders`, but did not use.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lrow As Long
Dim AmountCol as Long
Dim BillCol as Long
Dim USDCol as Long
Dim Rngheaders As Range
Dim x as long

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CSV Data PR")
Set Rngheaders = ws.Range("1:1")
lrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

AmountCol = Rngheaders.Find(What:="Amount").Column
BillCol = Rngheaders.Find(What:="Bill.qty").Column
USDCol = Rngheaders.Find(What:="In USD").Column

For x= 2 to lrow
     ws.Cells(x,USDCol) = ws.Cells(x, AmountCol) * ws.Cells(x, BillCol)
Next x
```

Comment: I don't need this but I'm saving this code just incase I do. I like it, so simple, neat, and precise. Not a fan of the other answers calling functions and what-not.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Exactly what I looked for, and indeed - no clue actually why I did not use the header reference row.

Answer (score 2):

Please consider using a User Defined Function for your purpose. Paste the function's code in a standard code module.

```
Function BillTotal(R As Long) As Double
    ' 07 Mar 2019
    ' returns -1 in case of error

    Dim Amt As Long
    Dim Qty As Long

    Application.Volatile
    On Error Resume Next
    Amt = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("amount", Rows(1), 0)
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        Qty = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("bill.qty", Rows(1), 0)
    End If
    If Err Then
        BillTotal = -1
    Else
        BillTotal = Val(Cells(R, Amt).Value) * Val(Cells(R, Qty).Value)
    End If
End Function
```

In the cell in which you wish to have the result write the function call like this.

```
=BillTotal(Row())
```

As an alternative you can use the same function to realize your original idea. Just call it in a For ... Next loop and write the result to a cell defined by R and C where row number R is provided by the loop and C may be obtained from a MATCH function as is shown in my function. If using in this way, the line `Application.Volatile` wouldn't be required.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lrow As Long
Dim Amount As Range
Dim Bill As Range
Dim USD As Range
Dim Rngheaders As Range
Dim counter As Integer

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CSV Data PR")
Set Rngheaders = ws.Range("1:1")
lrow = ws.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row - 1

Set Amount = ws.Rows(1).Find(What:="Amount")
Set Bill = ws.Rows(1).Find(What:="Bill.qty")
Set USD = ws.Rows(1).Find(What:="In USD")


For counter = 1 To lrow
    USD.Offset(counter, 0).Value = Amount.Offset(counter, 0).Value * Bill.Offset(counter, 0).Value
Next counter
```

I set the variable type of the Amount, Bill and USD ranges

As those are already ranges, you can refer to them directly. No need to use `Range(USD.Address)`

Also, you're not using this line: `Set Rngheaders = ws.Range("1:1")`

Give a try and let me know if it works. I couldn't test it.